# google maps api v3 directions_changed event inside a loop

Tags: google-maps-api-3, callback

I have a route that is a combination of multiple sub routes. (By sub routes i mean multiple DirectionsRenderer objects)

I also have a loop where i go throught all of the DirectionsRenderer objects and attach "directions_changed" event to all of them.

Unfortunatelly only that last DirectionsRenderer object fires the event when i try to test what happens when i drag the polyline.

Here is a part of my code:

```
for(var k=0; k<directionsRenderers.length; k++)
{

     var directionsRenderer = directionsRenderers[k];
     var a = registerDirectionsChangedEvent(k,directionsRenderer);  
}


function registerDirectionsChangedEvent(index, directionsRenderer)
{
    this.index = index;
    this.directionsRenderer = directionsRenderer;

    var that = this;
    var a = google.maps.event.addListener(this.directionsRenderer, "directions_changed", function()
    {
       var newStopPoint;
       var directionsResult = that.directionsRenderer.getDirections();
       var route = directionsResult.routes[0];
       var legs = route.legs;
       var legsIndex = 0;

       for(var i=0; i<legs.length; i++)
       {
          var cLeg = legs[i];
          var viaWaypoints = cLeg.via_waypoints;
          if(viaWaypoints.length > 0)
          {
             newStopPoint = viaWaypoints[0];
             if(that.index === 1) legsIndex += 9;
             else if(that.index === 2) legsIndex += 18;

             break;
          }
          legsIndex++;
      }

      addNewStopPoint(newStopPoint,legsIndex);
   });

    return a;
}
```

As i have mentioned above not only the last DirectionsRenderer object get fired but the ones before the last event do not implement the default behaviour.

Maybe you have noticed that i use:

```
this.index = index;
this.directionsRenderer = directionsRenderer;

var that = this;
```

event without it it still does not work.

I also tried to use a function created inside the loop like this:

```
(function someFunction(a,b){//do something here})(a,b);
```

but still no luck!

any advice how to make it works?

Comment: Function closure should work (a "createDirections" function which holds closure on the route and adds the direction_changed listener).

Comment: directions are created inside another function. then i loop throught them and attach directions_changed event

Comment: That isn't the same (which is why it doesn't work...)

Comment: why should i put the event in the same function that i created the object?

Answer (score 0):

Use function closure, this is probably a duplicate (not tested):

```
for(var k=0; k<directionsRenderers.length; k++)
{
     var directionsRenderer = directionsRenderers[k];
     var a = registerDirectionsChangedEvent(k,directionsRenderer);  
}


function registerDirectionsChangedEvent(index, directionsRenderer)
{
    var a = google.maps.event.addListener(directionsRenderer, "directions_changed", function()
    {
       var newStopPoint;
       var directionsResult = directionsRenderer.getDirections();
       var route = directionsResult.routes[0];
       var legs = route.legs;
       var legsIndex = 0;

       for(var i=0; i<legs.length; i++)
       {
          var cLeg = legs[i];
          var viaWaypoints = cLeg.via_waypoints;
          if(viaWaypoints.length > 0)
          {
             newStopPoint = viaWaypoints[0];
             if(index === 1) legsIndex += 9;
             else if(index === 2) legsIndex += 18;

             break;
          }
          legsIndex++;
      }

      addNewStopPoint(newStopPoint,legsIndex);
   });

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Seems like google maps has some bug or protection to not be able to attach the directions_changed event to more than one DirectionRenderer object?!?!?

Comment: well i tried to do it outside loop and it still did not work. Only the last directionsrenderer object fires the event. the ones before it do not! If you don't believe me try it yourself

Comment: How?  You haven't provided enough code for a functioning example.

Comment: I think that the reason it does not work is because before i drag the route curve i already have EIGHT waypoints which is the limit:)

Comment: That shouldn't cause the directions_changed event not to fire, if it is a problem you should get an error response from the DirectionsService, you haven't provided that code, so can't see if you are checking for that (or informing the user if an error occurs)