# Directions API GMAPv3 showing multiple paths using multiple DirectionRenderer objects BUT not able to bind directions_changed event to all of them

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am unable to bind directions_changed event to all the direction rendering objects.

**Requirement:**
 1. I am trying to draw all suggested paths between point A and B.
 2. Paths has to be draggable.
 3. Not using any waypoints. 
 4. When a path is changed by dragging I want to capture information due to the change and thus listening to the **directions_changed** event.

**Progress till now:**
I have had success with showing multiple paths on map, they are draggable and everything works fine till the rendering part.

**Issue:**
Now in example given here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });
```

The above lines bind the function to the event. BUT here there is only one DirectionRenderer Object (**directionsDisplay**)

In my case I am creating multiple objects to render all paths

```
var request = {
    origin: origin_var,
    destination: destin_var,
 provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {

                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: gm_map['{SGQ}'],
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                     draggable: true,
                });

            }
    }
  });
}
```

Now I cannot bind the directions_changed event to all these and thus though there are multiple routes showing up I cannot fire the event when they are dragged.

Note: I have tried adding parameter to the constructor like

```
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: gm_map['{SGQ}'],
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                     draggable: true,
                     directions_changed:alert("Directions are changed"),
                });
```

But all what happens is this function gets called when the page loads and then nothing happens when I drag.

I have searched this over internet but no solution.

related similar posts but no answer there as well(very old though)
  [google maps api v3 directions_changed event inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565434/google-maps-api-v3-directions-changed-event-inside-a-loop)
  https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5387

Comment: Why do you say "Now I cannot bind the directions_changed event to all these"?  Assign it to a variable, add the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the directionsRenderer.  Add the event handler to that. Use function closure to keep the two associated.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
      createDirectionsRenderer(i, response);
    }
  } else alert("directions request failed:+ status);
});

function createDirectionsRenderer(i, response) {
   var dirRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
         map: gm_map['{SGQ}'],
         directions: response,
         routeIndex: i,
         draggable: true,
       }));
   google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'directions_changed', function() {
     alert("Directions are changed, route index="+i);
   });
}
```